# Handle UIApplicationDelegate callback on own custom class than AppDelegate class

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am trying to register push notification via a method `registerForPushNotification()` and want to handle all the delegate callbacks on this very said class instead of the `AppDelegate` class. Somehow, after implementing the delegate `UIApplicationDelegate`, I still don't get the callbacks to fire. Is there a way to do so?

```
public class PushNotification: NSObject {
  public var window: UIWindow?
  var token: Data = Data()
  var userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]!


  @objc public static func registerForPushNotification() {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
      (granted, error) in
      print("Permission granted: \(granted)")
    }
    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
  }
}

extension PushNotification : UIApplicationDelegate {
  public func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    let tokenParts = deviceToken.map { data -> String in
      return String(format: "%02.2hhx", data)
    }

    let token = tokenParts.joined()
    print("Device Token: \(token)")
  }

  public func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print("Failed to register: \(error)")
  }
  public func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    print("notification received")
    self.userInfo = userInfo

    completionHandler(.noData)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So for that to work, you have to do 3 things!

- adopt the protocol
- conform to the protocol requirements
- set the delegate.

But you're not setting the delegate anywhere (ie you're not doing something similar to `UIApplication.delegate = self`, so no you won't get the callbacks!

If you want to do such a thing, I recommend you to follow [this hack](http://thebugcode.github.io/how-to-have-a-clean-appdelegate-a-simple-and-elegant-architecture/). Make sure you read the comments below!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your custom class instance will get notified, even if it adopts the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol.

The callbacks defined in the protocol are called on the **registered application delegate**; i.e., the object referenced by the `delegate` property of `UIApplication.shared` (which is, in turn, the object that represents the running application).

The app delegate is set **automatically** at launch by instantiating the class specified by name in main.m (for Objective-C code):

```
@import UIKit;
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(
            argc, 
            argv, 
            nil, 
            NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]) // <-- THIS
        ); 
    }
}
```

...or marked with `@UIApplicationMain` (in Swift code):

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain // <-- THIS
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

Answer (score 0):

`UIApplicationDelegate` is just a set of protocols that an AppDelegate must be conformed to.

A delegate of an object needs to be explicitly assigned in order for the object to interact with it.
Just like how you would assign (for example) the delegate of a table as `tableView.delegate = self`, the Delegate for the application is assigned to the `AppDelegate` class by default.

Since `AppDelegate` is already handling everything, you can extend it and include your own functionality in there, or you could create your custom delegate and then have it handle all the responsibilities that the AppDelegate would. There isn't a way to split the Application callbacks across multiple delegates.

However, if you still want to handle the callbacks from remote notifications in your own class what you can do is -

1. Add the functions to handle remote notifications in the AppDelegate
2. Have each function post a notification
3. Handle all such notifications in your own class